# alloy: arity issue when checking constraint with an assertion

Tags: logic, alloy

I've recently started to experiment with alloy for a project, and I have run into an issue unequal arities. Here is a simplified example. I have four signatures:

- Word
- Definition
- Document: a document has a text (a sequence of words)
- Dictionary: a dictionary maps a sequence of words to a sequence of definitions (to keep it simple, let's say that a word should have exactly one definition)

Here is a minimal code example:

```
module dictionaries

open util/relation as relation

sig Word {}

sig Definition {}

sig Document {
    text: seq Word
}

sig Dictionary {
    entries: seq Word,
    defseq: seq Definition,
    define: Word->Definition,
}{
    //dictionary maps word to def only for the word present in dictionary
    dom[define] = elems [entries] function [define, elems [entries]]
    //content of the list of defintions
    defseq = entries.define
}

//assert all word in a  dictionary have a definition
assert all_word_defined {
    all w: Word | all dict: Dictionary | some def: Definition |
    //w in dict.entries implies w->def in dict.define
}

check all_word_defined
```

So my questions are:

1. How do I constrain dictionaries so that each word in the dictionary maps to exactly one definition? Is it correct to do it as in the code above?
2. How do I check that this constraint is respected with an assertion? Obviously the bit of code `w in dict.entries implies w->def in dict.define` does not work, because `w in dict.entries`and `w->def in dict.define` do not have the same arity, and I get the error message "in can be used only between 2 expressions of the same arity"...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're struggling with `seq` and `assertions` more than arity.

- `seq` is not very common in Alloy, you only use it when you need to change the ordering of elements. In this example, I do not see any need for ordering in the current description.
- Assertions verify invariants of the whole model. What you try to assert is more a *fact* that you state in the model than what you assert. Assertions are useful if you have defined operations and want to verify that certain things can never happen regardless of how those operations are executed and in what order. I.e. the assertions verify the *consequences* of the model, not the facts. (Although sometimes it is useful to verify something in other words.)
- Alloy is incredibly powerful in navigating through *global* tables. Despite looking object oriented, the trick is to understand that fields are actually global tables that are joined. (This is what took me a long time to get.)
- You should not have redundant information in the model. You `entries`, `defseq` and `define` can be modelled with functions on the `define` table.
- The base language is very powerful. For a problem of this size you often do not need any utilities. Especially relation seems quite redundant after you feel the relational model of Alloy.

Ok, step by step:

> A Documents is a sequence of words:

I would just make a Document a set of Word because that more natural and a lot easier to use. In *this* problem, the ordering of words does not play a role so using normal sets is ok it seems? (Counting the words would require a seq.)

```
 sig Word {}
 sig Document {
   text: Word
 }
```

> A dictionary maps a sequence of words to a sequence of definitions (to keep it simple, let's say that a word should have exactly one definition)

I think you mean that a Dictionary can map *a* word to one definition? Does EVERY word have an entry? Or are there some words that have an entry? You say 'a' which I take as *some* words having one Definition? If so:

```
 sig Definition {}
 sig Dictionary {
   define : Word -> one Definition,
 }
```

The `define` table (which is `Dictionary->Word->Definition`) has a constrain that for a given Dictionary->Word combination, there must be `one` Definition. This means not all Words have to be in the table, but if a Word is in the table then there must be exactly one Definition. (you can model this also with other constraints. Best is to write out a table and look at the columns.)

You define `entries` as the set of Word in the Dictionary. You can model this better as a function:

```
 fun Dictionary.entries : set Word {
   this.define.univ
 }
```

The first join selects the `this` Dictionary in the `define` table and removes the first column. The second join removes the last column.

And similar for `defseq`:

```
 fun Dictionary.defseq : set Definition {
    this.define[univ]
 }
```

The box join `[]` just joins the inside of the square brackets with the *first column* of the table before it, leaving the Definition column. That is:

```
 (univ).(this.define)
```

> How do I check that this constraint is respected with an assertion

I think it is not clear what you try to assert. (Which is the power of a formal language that you discover this!) In Alloy you *state* as a fact that a Word in a Dictionary maps to one Definition. There is no use asserting something you have defined as a fact. Before you can assert you first need more definitions.

Normally you start writing a predicate and then look for examples of your model. For example, if we want to see one of the infinite Dictionary's then we could write:

```
pred show( d : Dictionary ) {
     d.define.univ = Word
}
run show for 5
```

In this example, you will see a Dictionary where every word has a Definition.

I've written a blog that might be useful for you: http://aqute.biz/2017/07/15/Alloy.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the blog post! It is certainly useful to think of mappings as tables. I know that I should not try to assert what is actually a fact. The problem is that I'm working with a base from someone else, and also that I'm very good at creating my own facts yet (I can see counterexamples in the instances). So assertions help me to doublecheck that I expressed my facts correctly! Especially when I get a lot of instances, and I don't want to click through a few hundreds just to see that all the instances are correct...

Comment: PS: the alloy analyzer is not very happy with your proposition `fun Dictionary.entries { this.define.univ }` (it tells me that there is a syntax error).

Comment: Can you put your model on Github or so?